# NetBeans java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Another beginner question here. I have three *.java files in my project. I am supposed to be able to run "Main.java", which will in turn run the "example.java" if I enter 1 as an input.

This works well with Eclipse. However in NetBeans after entering 1, the java applet will open up and nothing will be drawn. The error is:

Can't handle shape example
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example

So it's not finding "example.java", but all three files are in the same "src" folder.. any ideas?

Here are all three files:

Painter.java:

```
package recursion;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
/*
 * open a frame named aShape and drew the given shape 
 */

public class Painter extends Component {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static int SIZE = 600;
private static Painter painter;
private static Graphics g;
private static String shape = null;

// Create a frame and display it
public static void draw(String aShape) {
    shape = aShape;        
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(shape);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    painter =  new Painter();
    frame.add(painter, null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

// returns the Frame's width
public static int getFrameWidth () {
    return painter.getSize().width;
}

// returns the Frame's height
public static int getFrameHeight () {
    return painter.getSize().height;
}

// changes the color of the lines to be drawn
public static void setColor (String color) {
    if (color.equals("red")){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
    }           
    else if (color.equals("blue")){
        g.setColor(Color.blue);  
    }
    else if (color.equals("green")){
        g.setColor(Color.green);  
    }       
}

//    public static void drawLine (Pixel p1, Pixel p2) {
  //    drawLine((int)Math.round(p1.getX()),(int)Math.round(p1.getY()),    (int)Math.round(p2.getX()),(int)Math.round(p2.getY()));
//      
 //   }

// Draw a line on the frame
public static void drawLine (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    g.drawLine(x1, getFrameHeight()-y1, x2, getFrameHeight()-y2);

}

// Set the default size of the window frame to SIZE*SIZE pixels
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE);
}

// paint the frame - draw the shape given (call the draw method in that shape object)
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Painter.g = g;
    try{
        Object myShape = (Class.forName(shape)).newInstance();
        Object [] objs = null;
        Class [] classes = null;
        (Class.forName(shape)).getMethod("draw", classes).invoke(myShape, objs);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Can't handle shape " + shape);
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println(e.getCause());

    }



 }

}
```

example.java:

```
package recursion;

/*
the class example draw a line. 
*/
public class example {


public void draw(){
    int width = Painter.getFrameHeight()/2; // find the x coordinate of the center of the frame
    int height = Painter.getFrameWidth()/2; // find the y coordinate of the center of the frame
    int maxRadius = Math.min(width, height)/2;
    // change the color of the line to be drawn to red
    Painter.setColor("red");
    // draw a line from (width, height) to (width+maxRadius, height+maxRadius)
    Painter.drawLine(width, height, width+maxRadius, height+maxRadius);
}

}
```

Main.java:

```
package recursion;

import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * the class main get from the user the shape he wish to draw,
 * and call the drew method of the desired shape .
 */
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {        


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Please enter the number of the shape you wish to draw:\n" +
            " 1-example\n" +
            " 2-BasicStar\n" +
            " 3-Snowflake\n" +
            " 4-SuperSnowflake\n" +
            " 5-KochCurve\n" +
            " 6-KochSnowflake\n");
    int shape = sc.nextInt();

    // chooses which shape to draw based on the number received
    switch(shape){
    /*
     *  An example given to you so you can see how the painted works.
     *  This example opens a frame, and draws a red line.
     */
    case 1:
        drawExample();
        break;
    case 2:
        drawBasicStar();
        break;
    case 3:
        drawSnowflake();
        break;
    case 4:
        drawSuperSnowflake();
        break;
    case 5:
        drawKochCurve();
        break;
    case 6:
        drawKochSnowflake();
        break;
    default: System.out.println("invalid shape");
    }

    sc.close();
}

// Draw the example line
public static void drawExample(){
    Painter.draw("example");
}

// Draw a BasicStar
public static void drawBasicStar(){
    Painter.draw("BasicStar");
}

// Draw a Snowflake
public static void drawSnowflake(){
    Painter.draw("Snowflake");
}

// Draw a SuperSnowflake
public static void drawSuperSnowflake(){
    Painter.draw("SuperSnowflake");
}

// Draw a KochCurve
public static void drawKochCurve(){
    Painter.draw("KochCurve");
}

// Draw a KochSnowflake
public static void drawKochSnowflake(){
    Painter.draw("KochSnowflake");
}

}
```

Comment: PLease add the `stacktrace` and point to that line. may be some import is missing.

Comment: You should check the bin folder or where ever netbeans places compiled classes ans see if there is a `example.class` file there.

Comment: I checked the folder where all the classes are stored (\build\classes\recursion) and the file is there. Smit, I'm not sure what you mean (beginner here :/ )

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `paint(Graphics g)` function:

```
(Class.forName(shape)).getMethod("draw", classes).invoke(myShape, objs);
```

While trying to get the class with `Class.forName(String)` function you should provide  the [*`fully qualified name`*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) of the desired class. That is, to get the class `"example"` you should provide: `Class.forName("recursion.example")`.

- For custom painting we should not override the `paint(Graphics g)` function rather `paintComponent(Graphics g)` function and `super.paintComponent(g)` should be called inside this function.
- Your `Painter` class is extending `Component`, instead extend the `JComponent`.
- You are passing `null` in place of constraint of `frame.add(component, border_layout_constraint)`: don't do that. JFrame's content pane uses `BorderLayout` as default. So use constraint from one of this layout.

Off Topic: class name should start with capital letter.

Comment: Yep that did it. Funnily enough these starting classes were made by our university faculty. We are now supposed to implement the methods. They take off points for mistakes regarding these conventions, and then they make the same mistakes.. shame on them :) Anyway thanks!